# start a simple jar application in macbook from terminal

Tags: java, macos, java-home

I installed java on my MacBook, I'm trying to start a simple hand that is in a jar but I just can't.

The command I launch is the following:

`java -cp sell.jar it.test.testina`

The error is always this:

> error: Cannot Find or Load the Main Class it.test.testina
> Launching the same command on Windows everything works correctly

java version "1.8.0.351".

I guess the problem is that I am not setting the classpath.

Thank you in advance for the helps.

I tried to set `java_home` in `bash_profile` but it does not work.

Below is my code in my class:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class testina {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,00");
        double dprice= Double.parseDouble( decimalFormat.format(4.551d));
        System.out.println(dprice);
    }
}
```

In this [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9c95b3f7b72182b609403d48e99ac6c020230117090034/ee35a0) I can see output of the command `jar tf sell.jar`

Comment: Please post the source up to the declaration of your main class. Note class names begin [upper case](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)

Comment: I try with lowercase and uppercase, the same problem

Comment: Please post output of the following *formatted as code* into your question: `jar tf sell.jar`

Comment: I modify the question and add a link containd the exrtact of command jar tf sell.jar

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9c95b3f7b72182b609403d48e99ac6c020230117090034/ee35a0

Comment: I don't see the file `it/test/testina.class` in your jar. It's likely that you have built the jar incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, that class is absent. *Is* it your main class anyway? Why is it in a package called 'test'? It would be a good idea to paste pom.xml *formatted as code in the question*